# How can I make a TableView push an above object out of the way when scrolling up?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

i.e. There is an object with specific data above a TableView, and when the TableView is scrolled up, I want the object above to be pushed off screen. Similar to the Maps app when you're looking at a business page, where there's the header, and then a TableView below with the phone, homepage, etc below.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make the "object" (view I'm assuming) a header view for your table.  As the table scrolls, so will your header.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1- Make the object with specific data above the tableview TableView
    Header. From the question it look like you need help for that also so here how you will do it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     // ...
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
     [headerView addSubview:imageView];
     UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XXX, YYY, XXX, YYY)];
     [headerView addSubview:labelView];
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
     [imageView release];
     [labelView release];
     [headerView release];
     // ...
}
```

2- Implement scrollview delegate inside check if the scrollview is tableview then hide you object (view).